# G++ error from previous declaration, error due to duplicate function name in includes

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, openmp, rcpp

I am writing a Rcpp code that include two library RcppArmadillo and trng4. However, when I include two header files (RcppArmadillo.h and trng/gamma_dist.hpp) it gives  compilation error.

```
 trng/special_functions.hpp:47:39: error: declaration of ‘float lgammaf(float) throw ()’ has a  different exception specifier
 extern "C" float lgammaf(float) throw();
include-fixed/math.h:476:14: error: from previous declaration ‘float lgammaf(float)’
extern float lgammaf(float);
```

Full compilation options are

```
-fopenmp -lgomp -DUSE_R -DNDEBUG -DDISABLE_SINGLE -DNTHROW -DDISABLE_FIO -I/usr/local/include -I"/Users/avi/Library/R/3.0/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/avi/Library/R/3.0/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC -pipe -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -c
```

Seems like the lgammaf is declared in both header files. I tried using -E with g++ option but that give ld warning " .o, file was built for unsupported file format" and give error function in not available in .Call when I try it to after loading in R. What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps out of context I am using trng4 package to develop a thread gibbs sampler (in openmp) that sample from gamma distribution. I am currently running this MacOS. But eventual it will run in linux server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do have a problem between Armadillo and trng4.  Maybe you should try to, if possible, separate your interface so that you do not need to include from both in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you prevent this issue by using #ifndef in each header file so that it's not defined a second time even if it's included a second time. But I guess these aren't your files are they...?

```
#ifndef __your_unique_header_name__

blah blah


#endif
```

Comment: I didn't understand. Are you saying to go and change RccpArmadillo.h or special_functions.hpp? There should be way that this can be done in easier manner. In fact each different library can have same function name but different functionality. We can usually access same function name from different library using namespace. But my question is how to exclude when two C libraries have same function name in their respective header files.

Comment: I don't think this recommendation is correct either.

Comment: I've always seen #ifndef in every header file, but it would technically be only needed in a header that more than one file might use (perhaps like special_functions in your case). Different header files can have the same function names because the linker will give them unique names based on the header file itself. But if the same header is included twice and it tries to define the function twice, the linker will come up with the exact same name. That's my understanding, anyway.

Comment: The #ifndef is an include guard which prevents inclusion of the same header twice.  Which is a good thing.  But it has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: Oh, I guess I read it wrong. I thought he said both were including the same header but he said the two headers contained the same function. Sorry 'bout that.